# Flutter firebase_admob show only once

Tags: dart, flutter, admob, interstitial

The following code show the banner ad at the bottom of the application and show interstitial ad when click. Interstitial ad is shown when the button is pressed. The problem is, when the app start and click button for the first time, the interstitial is shown but the interstitial is not shown starting from second time.
There are no errors and all log message show success. Is my code error? I'm testing on android device.

```
import 'package:firebase_admob/firebase_admob.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {

  final admobAppId = 'ca-app-pub-3940256099942544~3347511713';
  final bannerId = 'ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/6300978111';
  final interstitialId = 'ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/1033173712';

  BannerAd bannerAd;
  InterstitialAd interstitialAd;

  MyApp() {
    FirebaseAdMob.instance.initialize(appId: admobAppId);
    makeBannerAd();
    initInterstitialAd();
  }

  makeBannerAd() {
    bannerAd = BannerAd(
        adUnitId: bannerId,
        size: AdSize.smartBanner,
        listener: (MobileAdEvent me) {
          print('MobileAdEvent $me');
        });
    bannerAd
      ..load()
      ..show();
  }

  initInterstitialAd() {
    interstitialAd = InterstitialAd(
        adUnitId: interstitialId,
        listener: (MobileAdEvent me) {
          print(
              '========== Interstitial ad mobile ad event =========== \n $me');
          if (me == MobileAdEvent.closed) {
            print('Interstitial closed');
            loadInterstitialAd();
          }
        });
    loadInterstitialAd();
  }

  loadInterstitialAd() {
    interstitialAd.load().then((val) {
      if (val) {
        print('Interstitial ad loaded callback success');
      } else {
        print('Interstitial ad loaded callback failed');
      }
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text('AdMob plugin test'),
        ),
        body: Center(
          child: RaisedButton(
            child: Text('Show Interstitial!'),
            onPressed: () {
              interstitialAd.show().then((val) {
                if (val) {
                  print('Interstitial ad show callback success');
                } else {
                  print('Interstitial ad show callback fail');
                }
              });
            },
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

**Update**
Following is the code with dispose(). It show up to 2 times.

```
class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {

  final admobAppId = 'ca-app-pub-3940256099942544~3347511713';
  final bannerId = 'ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/6300978111';
  final interstitialId = 'ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/1033173712';

  BannerAd bannerAd;
  InterstitialAd interstitialAd;
  MobileAdTargetingInfo mobileAdTargetingInfo;

  MyApp() {
    FirebaseAdMob.instance.initialize(appId: admobAppId);
    makeBannerAd();
    initInterstitialAd();
  }

  makeBannerAd() {
    bannerAd = BannerAd(
        adUnitId: bannerId,
        size: AdSize.smartBanner,
        listener: (MobileAdEvent me) {
          print('Banner => MobileAdEvent $me');
        });
    bannerAd
      ..load()
      ..show();
  }

  initInterstitialAd() {
    interstitialAd = InterstitialAd(
        adUnitId: interstitialId,
        listener: (MobileAdEvent me) {
          print(
              '========== Interstitial ad mobile ad event =========== $me');
          if (me == MobileAdEvent.closed) {
            print('Interstitial closed');
            interstitialAd.dispose().then((val){
              if(val){
                loadInterstitialAd();
              }else{
              }
            });
          } else if (me == MobileAdEvent.failedToLoad) {
            print('Interstitial failed to load');
            loadInterstitialAd();
          }
        });
    loadInterstitialAd();
  }

  loadInterstitialAd() {
    interstitialAd.load();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text('AdMob plugin test'),
        ),
        body: Center(
          child: RaisedButton(
            child: Text('Show Interstitial!'),
            onPressed: () {
              interstitialAd.show();
            },
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 12):

I had the same issue and resolved it with the *InterstitialAd* object as shown:

```
InterstitialAd myInterstitial() {
    return InterstitialAd(
      adUnitId: InterstitialAd.testAdUnitId,
      targetingInfo: targetingInfo,
      listener: (MobileAdEvent event) {
        if (event == MobileAdEvent.failedToLoad) {
          interstitialAd..load();
        } else if (event == MobileAdEvent.closed) {
          interstitialAd = myInterstitial()..load();
        }
      },
    );
  }
@override
void initState() {
    FirebaseAdMob.instance.initialize(appId: 
        FirebaseAdMob.testAppId);
    interstitialAd = myInterstitial()..load();
    super.initState();
}
@override
void dispose() {
    interstitialAd?.dispose();
    super.dispose();
}
```

Call method:

```
interstitialAd
  ..load()
  ..show();
```

From my understanding, you can use the listener to recursively call the initial *InterstitialAd* object when the event is closed. My source is from [Tensor Programming Youtube Channel](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=r9wbxYE2DYY&t=644s) He explains it much better than me.

Comment: This works great! The only method that worked and no need to dispose every time which was a ridiculous solution. This should be the accepted answer.

Answer (score 2):

I modified and fixed the code as follow and I also posted in the [github issue](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/27520#issuecomment-462036114). Now, whenever the button is pressed the ad is shown. I tested 10+ times and it work well. It seem InterstitialAd need to create every time the ad is wanted to show. But I don't know exactly. If there is someone who knows why, please explain me.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:firebase_admob/firebase_admob.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  BannerAd myBanner;

  MyApp() {
    FirebaseAdMob.instance.initialize(appId: FirebaseAdMob.testAppId);
    myBanner =
        BannerAd(adUnitId: BannerAd.testAdUnitId, size: AdSize.smartBanner);
    myBanner
      ..load()
      ..show();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text("Interstitial Ad test"),
        ),
        body: Center(
          child: RaisedButton(
            child: Text("Interstitial ad"),
            onPressed: () {
              InterstitialAd interstitialAd = new InterstitialAd(
                  adUnitId: InterstitialAd.testAdUnitId,
                  listener: (MobileAdEvent e) {
                    print("Mobile ad event => $e");
                  });
              interstitialAd.load().then((val) {
                interstitialAd.show();
              });
            },
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I faced the same problem. The solution is simple.

Just use `interstitialAd.dispose()` to dispose the ad so that a new interstitial ad get loaded the next time.

Comment: I added dispose() to callback function closed condition it worked for second time but when I press the button third time it show this error "<Google> Request Error: Will not send request because interstitial object has been used."

Comment: Oh... can you share some code or screenshot or anything?

Comment: what about if I don't use a `Statefull` widget?

Answer (score 0):

Leave an example of the way I work.
I hope it helps.

```
void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Intersticial',
      navigatorKey: Get.key, // use get: ^1.6.3
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: MyHomePage(title: 'Flutter Intersticial'),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  MyHomePage({Key key, this.title}) : super(key: key);
  final String title;

  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {

  InterstitialAd _interstitialAd;

  InterstitialAd createIntersticialAd(){
    return InterstitialAd(
      adUnitId: AD_MOB_AD_INTERSTICIAL_1_ID,
      targetingInfo: AdMobUtil.targetingInfo,
      listener: (MobileAdEvent event) {
        print("InterstitialAd event is $event");
        // Dispose InterstitialAd 
        if (event == MobileAdEvent.closed)
           dispose();
      },
    );
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    //
    // dispose intersticialAd
    //
    _interstitialAd?.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(widget.title),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: <Widget>[
            Text(
              'Go to second page',
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        onPressed: () {
          //
          // create intersticialAd and send by parameter
          //
          _interstitialAd ??= createIntersticialAd();
          Get.to(SecondPage(interstitialAd: _interstitialAd,));
        },
        tooltip: 'Go to Second page',
        child: Icon(Icons.arrow_forward),
      ), // This trailing comma makes auto-formatting nicer for build methods.
    );
  }
}


class SecondPage extends StatefulWidget {
  //
  // define intersticial  final
  //
  final InterstitialAd interstitialAd;

  const SecondPage({Key key, this.interstitialAd}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _SecondPageState createState() => _SecondPageState();
}

class _SecondPageState extends State<SecondPage> {

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container();
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    //
    // show intersticial ad
    //
    widget.interstitialAd..load()..show();
    super.dispose();
  }
}
```

The banner will open when you return from the second page.

I used this package for navigation: https://pub.dev/packages/get

If helped mark as useful ..;)

Answer (score 0):

May be am late here but this might help for future viewers. Here is the most efficient and best method to this, so that you can watch ads one after another. For all types of ads, here I have given examples of Interstitial and Rewarded, the same logic for others. Also here you can find how to load the ad again after it failed.

Full code:

```
InterstitialAd _interstitialAd;
  RewardedAd _rewardedAd;

      void interstitialAdload () {
        InterstitialAd.load(
            adUnitId: '<test ad>',
            request: AdRequest(),
            adLoadCallback: InterstitialAdLoadCallback(
              onAdLoaded: (InterstitialAd ad) {
                // Keep a reference to the ad so you can show it later.
                this._interstitialAd = ad;
                ad.fullScreenContentCallback = FullScreenContentCallback(
                  onAdShowedFullScreenContent: (InterstitialAd ad) =>
                      print('$ad onAdShowedFullScreenContent.'),
                  onAdDismissedFullScreenContent: (InterstitialAd ad) {
                    print('$ad onAdDismissedFullScreenContent.');
                    ad.dispose();
                  },
                  onAdFailedToShowFullScreenContent: (InterstitialAd ad, AdError error) {
                    print('$ad onAdFailedToShowFullScreenContent: $error');
                    ad.dispose();
                  },
                  onAdImpression: (InterstitialAd ad) {
                    interstitialAdload(); // <<<-------------- LOAD AD AGAIN WHEN THE USER WATCHES IT SO THAT ITS READY TO BE WATCHED JUST AFTER THE IMPRESSION OCCURS
                    print('$ad impression occurred.');
                  }
                );
              },
              onAdFailedToLoad: (LoadAdError error) {
                interstitialAdload(); // <<<-------------- LOAD AD AGAIN IF IT FAILS
                print('InterstitialAd failed to load: $error');
              },
            ));
      }
    
      void rewardedAdLoad() {
        RewardedAd.load(
            adUnitId: '<test ad>',
            request: AdRequest(),
        rewardedAdLoadCallback: RewardedAdLoadCallback(
        onAdLoaded: (RewardedAd ad) {
        print('$ad loaded.');
        // Keep a reference to the ad so you can show it later.
        this._rewardedAd = ad;
        ad.fullScreenContentCallback = FullScreenContentCallback(
          onAdShowedFullScreenContent: (RewardedAd ad) =>
              print('$ad onAdShowedFullScreenContent.'),
          onAdDismissedFullScreenContent: (RewardedAd ad) {
            print('$ad onAdDismissedFullScreenContent.');
            ad.dispose();
          },
          onAdFailedToShowFullScreenContent: (RewardedAd ad, AdError error) {
            print('$ad onAdFailedToShowFullScreenContent: $error');
            ad.dispose();
          },
          onAdImpression: (RewardedAd ad)
          {
            print('$ad impression occurred.');
            rewardedAdLoad(); // <<<-------------- LOAD AD AGAIN WHEN THE USER WATCHES IT SO THAT ITS READY TO BE WATCHED JUST AFTER THE IMPRESSION OCCURS
          }
        );
        },
        onAdFailedToLoad: (LoadAdError error) {
          rewardedAdLoad(); // <<<-------------- LOAD AD AGAIN IF IT FAILS
        print('RewardedAd failed to load: $error');
        },
        )
        );
      }
    
      void showInterstitialAd() {
        _interstitialAd.show();
      }
   
    
      void showRewardedAd() {
        _rewardedAd.show(onUserEarnedReward: (RewardedAd ad, RewardItem rewardItem) {
          // Reward the user for watching an ad.
          reward();
        });
      }
```

Comment: If it helped you please upvote and mark it correct and let me know if any doubts or error occurs.

Comment: I believe it wont give any error as I have tested it myself and using in my own app